# Safety standards for autopilots

Tags: software, autonomous-car, reliability

Does anyone know if where i could learn more about the software safety standards for real time applications, such as for car and plane autopilots?

Both EU and US suggestions are very much wanted.

Comment: yes, someone knows ... is that really all you want to know? ... this is a Q&A site ... not a forum for suggestions ... shopping questions are also off topic

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ole, but I'm afraid that questions which are polls or surveys are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather broad, only vaguely on-topic, and not a Q&A type of question...

However, I'll give it ago... and fortunately, the US and EU are reasonably well aligned.

**Automotive**

The primary functional safety standard for the automotive world is ISO 26262... a massive standard of 13 parts, addressing the whole software and systems engineering lifecycle.

Associated with this, you have ISO/SAE 21434 which addresses the Cybersecurity side of things, and supersedes the longer standing SAE J3061.

As autonomy becomes a bigger issue, a number of parallel projects are ongoing, including UL4600 and several ISO-led works

**Aerospace**

In the aerospace domain, it's a little more complex and non-integrated... airborne software falls within DO-178C, while programmable electronics comes under DO-254

Work is ongoing to revise these for UAVs

**Software-level**

At the software level, testing has been internationally standardised with ISO/IEC/IEEE 29119 (a multi part standard) which brought together a number of existing US and UK led standards in harmonised form... and has been further developed by an multi-national working group ISO/IEC JTC1/SC7/WG26.

Associated with this is the ISO/IEC 250xx SQuaRE family of standards which define quality measures.

**Availability**

Unfortunately, international standards are covered by copyright and are not freely available - hence no links in this answer.  They can be sourced thorough the appropriate national body (eg BSI in the UK)

My day job revolves around a lot of these... I'm happy to discuss further (probably better offline... see profile)

Comment: Hi, should I reach out to you through any specific platforms?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrewbanks/